# What Happen When Check Condition is Missing From The For Loop

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a code snippet,

```
function* powers(n) {
   for (let current = n;; current *= n) {
     yield current;
   }
}
```

Why there is no checking condition in the for loop (see two `;;`)?

Seems the code will continue to run like a `while` true loop. Why not using a `while` instead doing this. It makes code hard to read anyway.

Comment: not using while because it applies calaculation to current of *= n

Comment: Yes you are totally right.

Comment: @nathan no, thats not in question. Please read questions more carefully.

Comment: @Jonas: the only way the question makes sense is if the OP doesn’t know what yield means. Also the answers posted here so far are explaining what yield is. So I think this is a valid dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's equivalent to no check at all.

If it weren't for the initialization and final (end-of-loop) expressions, it would be like `while (true) { yield current; }`

From [MDN - `for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (emphasis mine):

> ## condition
>
> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to `true`, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. **If omitted, the condition always evaluates to `true`**. If the expression evaluates to `false`, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

To understand the purpose of that function, you'd have to look into the [`yield` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield). An example of usage would be:

```
var p = powers(2);
console.log(p.next()); // 2
console.log(p.next()); // 4, 8, 16 and on...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a generator function provided in ES6.

> Calling a generator function does not execute its body immediately; an
>   iterator object for the function is returned instead. When the
>   iterator's next() method is called, the generator function's body is
>   executed until the first yield expression, which specifies the value
>   to be returned from the iterator or, with yield*, delegates to another
>   generator function.

When we call a generator function, only the part till the first yield is executed. What you have shown iterates a variable with `current *= n`.

Since it does not require an exit condition, it is skipped. The for loop will be executed the number of times the function is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A